# sed regex blindness

Tags: sed

I'm having some oddness with sed regex, and can't figure out what's going on. (This is "sed (GNU sed) 4.9" on OSX/MacPorts.)
I've got a METAR data log file, and I'm wanting to get the cloud cover field:

```
2022/12/11 04:50 EGSH 110450Z AUTO 00000KT 0100 FZFG OVC001/// M04/M05 Q1009 
2022/12/11 05:20 EGSH 110520Z AUTO 00000KT 0100 FZFG OVC001/// M04/M05 Q1008 
2022/12/11 05:50 EGSH 110550Z 00000KT 0050 R27/0375N FZFG VV/// M05/M05 Q1008 NOSIG 
2022/12/11 06:20 EGSH 110620Z 00000KT 0050 R27/0375N FZFG VV/// M05/M05 Q1008 NOSIG
```

So I've got:

```
cat metar.log | sed -nE "s#(.*) EGSH .*(SKC|NCD|CLR|NSC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC|TCU|CB|VV)([^ ]*) .*#\1 \2\3#p"
```

which works as expected and gives what I want:

```
2022/12/11 04:50 OVC001///
2022/12/11 05:20 OVC001///
2022/12/11 05:50 VV///
2022/12/11 06:20 VV///
```

But if I combine the last two capture groups (note the removed brackets near the end):

```
cat metar.log | sed -nE "s#(.*) EGSH .*(SKC|NCD|CLR|NSC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC|TCU|CB|VV[^ ]*) .*#\1 \2#p"
```

Now the result:

```
2022/12/11 05:50 VV///
2022/12/11 06:20 VV///
```

Why doesn't this work the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making it `(...CB|VV[^ ]*)` you changed your original regexp `(...CB|VV)([^ ]*)` to only allow extra non-blanks after `VV`, not after any of the other `|`-separated strings. Try this instead:

```
$ sed -nE 's#(.*) EGSH .*((SKC|NCD|CLR|NSC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC|TCU|CB|VV)[^ ]*) .*#\1 \2#p' metar.log
2022/12/11 04:50 OVC001///
2022/12/11 05:20 OVC001///
2022/12/11 05:50 VV///
2022/12/11 06:20 VV///
```

FWIW from the example you posted it **looks** like all you really need is:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1,2,9 metar.log
2022/12/11 04:50 OVC001///
2022/12/11 05:20 OVC001///
2022/12/11 05:50 VV///
2022/12/11 06:20 VV///
```

or:

```
$ awk '{print $1, $2, $9}' metar.log
2022/12/11 04:50 OVC001///
2022/12/11 05:20 OVC001///
2022/12/11 05:50 VV///
2022/12/11 06:20 VV///
```

or if you really want to stick with sed for some reason then:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.{16}) ([^ ]+ ){6}([^ ]+).*/\1 \3/' metar.log
2022/12/11 04:50 OVC001///
2022/12/11 05:20 OVC001///
2022/12/11 05:50 VV///
2022/12/11 06:20 VV///
```

Comment: Ah!  Yep, I was going blind, thanks! Unfortunately, I tried "cut" as a first solution and found out that metar data seems to have optional fields, so the one needed is not always the same number, hence the regex.

Comment: You're welcome. If you posted an example where we can't rely on the fields we might be able to help you come up with a better solution. Ask a new question if you want help with that.